# Calibration using quaternion

Tags: 3d, rotation, quaternion

I have an external hardware which gives me quaternion values. 
Now I would like to calibrate the device at a certain position and show tilt variations from that position on the UI.
For example, I have a small 3D plane model. Whatever position the device maybe, after calibration the model's back should be facing the user with the tail up and from that position the rotation should be relative to the device's rotation.
How to do that?
Simply recording the quaternion values at the calibration position and using that to subtract from the current quaternion values from the device and setting to the 3D model is not working.

Below is the code where I apply the calibrated values:

```
imu.xAxis = (Style.qX + (imuData.quatX - Style.bX))
imu.yAxis = (Style.qY + (imuData.quatY - Style.bY))
imu.zAxis = (Style.qZ + (imuData.quatZ - Style.bZ))
imu.wAxis = (Style.qW + (imuData.quatW - Style.bW))
```

where **qX,qY,qZ and qW** are the **initail postion** of the model, **quatX, quatY, quatZ and quatW** are the **current quaternion values** from the device and **bX, bY, bZ and bW** are the quaternion values at the **calibration position**.

Comment: you shouldn't be "subtracting" quaternions, the basic operation of quaternions is multiplication.

Comment: Ok. Can you please let me know the mathematics of how does calibration work for quaternions?

Comment: I suggest looking up a quaternion math library. The formulas needed are a bit complex and repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you concatenate rotations represented by quaternions. I suggest using a quaternion math library so you can avoid any typos when transcribing formulas.

The inverse of a quaternion is the conjugate. The operation to concatenate 2 rotation is the multiplication.

You should end up with:

```
imu.axis = Style.calibration * imuData.quat;
```

Where `Style.calibration` is the `calibration_position * inverse(initial_position)`

Comment: What does inverse mean here in calibration_position * inverse(initial_position)? From my understanding,calibration_position, is the quaternion value when the device is at the position in the 3D space at the time of calibration. But what does inverse(initial_position) mean and what is initial_position?

Comment: initial_position is the result returned by the device sensor in the orientation that you want to map to "neutral". The inverse operation undoes that rotation back to the identity (no rotation). calibration_position is the output orientation you want your app to see for an object that's in this "neutral" orientation. This gives you the flexibility to define your neutral orientation as something arbitrary, rather than just the identity (1 + 0i + 0j + 0k).